# Ant identifiying the a line above the current line

Tags: ant, build, ant-contrib

So i can retrieve a certain line in a file. Now i want to check the values in the line just above this line. How do i go about doing this in ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example uses the [Groovy ANT task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) to print the 3rd and 4th line of every Java file.

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="lib/groovy-all-2.1.0-rc-1.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="run">
        <fileset id="javafiles" dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>

        <groovy>
            ant.project.references.javafiles.each {
                def lines = new File(it.toString()).readLines()

                ant.echo lines[2]
                ant.echo lines[3]
            }
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```